# Что такое BuildContext в Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Объясните пожалуйста русским языком, что такое BuildContext. Я читал документации, но я не смог понять. Еще я читал [тут](https://flutterbyexample.com/build-context-class) и в итоге я еще больше не понял.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**BuildContext** это контекст в котором создается текущий виджет. Во Flutter все виджеты.

> In Flutter, everything is a widget.

А каждый виджет имеет свой собственный **BuildContext**, который будет родителем, вызвав функцию StatelessWidget.build или State.build. Поэтому часто пишут что **BuildContext** это не что иное, как ссылка на расположение виджета в структуре всех созданных виджетов.

Стоит добавить что buildContext позволяет реализовывать многие функции (например, showDialog, Theme.of и т. Д.) также продолжить цепочку билдеров, а их контексты будут отличаться.

Добавлю еще схему иерархии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

Можете смотреть на `BuildContext` как на объект-контейнер, который хранит виджет родителя. Это основа того, что такое контекст. Так же контекст позволяет получать информацию о ветке виджеты по ветке виджетов, но это уже доп. поведение.

Пример:

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Text("text"),
  )
);
```

Возьмем такую простую разметку. Тут три виджета, самый глубокий - `Text("text")`. У `Text("text")` есть метод`build(BuildContext context)`, как и у всех виджетов, который получает `BuildContext`. В случае с `Text("text")` метод `build(BuildContext context)` получит контекст, который будет хранить в себе `Container`.